# python - sorting strings via xml attribute, .text malforms xml data

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys, os.path
import string 

def sort_strings_file(xmlfile,typee):
    """sort all strings within given strings.xml file"""

    all_strings = {}
    orig_type=typee

    # read original file
    tree = ET.ElementTree()
    tree.parse(xmlfile)

    # iter over all strings, stick them into dictionary
    for element in list(tree.getroot()):
        all_strings[element.attrib['name']] = element.text

    # create new root element and add all strings sorted below
    newroot = ET.Element("resources")
    for key in sorted(all_strings.keys()):
        # Check for IDs
        if typee == "id":
            typee="item"

        # set main node type
        newstring = ET.SubElement(newroot, typee)

        #add id attrib
        if orig_type == "id":
            newstring.attrib['type']="id"

        # continue on
        newstring.attrib['name'] = key
        newstring.text = all_strings[key]


    # write new root element back to xml file
    newtree = ET.ElementTree(newroot)
    newtree.write(xmlfile, encoding="UTF-8")
```

This works great and all, but if a string start with like `<b>` it breaks badly.
EX

```
<string name="uploading_to"><b>%s</b> Odovzdávanie do</string>
```

becomes

```
<string name="uploading_to" />
```

I've looked into the xml.etree Element class, but it seems to only have .text method. I just need a way to pull everything in between xml tags. No, I can't change the input data. It comes directly from an Android APK ready to be translated, I cannot predict how / what the data comes in besides the fact that it must be valid XML Android code.

Comment: You seem to have mixed tabs and spaces. Now the indentation in the post is well out-of-whack, could you please clean that up?

Comment: Do you expect `.text` to *include*` the `<b>` tag, or it's contents?

Comment: I can't get StackOverflow to work correctly with Python. I post the code w/ correct indentation and it screws it up. I'm not messing around with it.

Comment: That is because you are mixing tabs and spaces. Tabs display at a width of 4 spaces once posted. Use your text editor to replace tabs with 8 spaces instead, then copy and paste.

Comment: I've fixed the tabs in this posting for you.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out. I even did that. http://pastebin.com/0b61eSvk

Comment: thank you :) now I'll read the answer you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `itertext()` method instead. `.text` only returns text directly contained *at the start* of the element:

```
>>> test = ET.fromstring('<elem>Sometext <subelem>more text</subelem> rest</elem>')
>>> test.text
'Sometext '
>>> ''.join(test.itertext())
'Sometext more text rest'
```

The `.itertext()` iterator on the other hand let's you find *all* text contained in the element, including inside nested elements.

If, however, you only want text *directly* contained in an element, skipping the contained children, you want the combination of `.text` and the `.tail` values of each of the children:

```
>>> (test.text or '') + ''.join(child.tail for child in test.getchildren())
'Sometext  middle  rest'
```

If you need to capture *everything* contained, then you need to do a little more work; capture the `.text`, and cast each child to text with `ElementTree.tostring()`:

```
>>> (test.text or '') + ''.join(ET.tostring(child) for child in test.getchildren())
'Sometext <subelem>more text</subelem> middle <subelem>other text</subelem> rest'
```

`ET.tostring()` takes the element tail into account. I use `(test.text or '')` because the `.text` attribute can be `None` as well.

You can capture that last method in a function:

```
def innerxml(elem):
    return (elem.text or '') + ''.join(ET.tostring(child) for child in elem.getchildren())
```

Comment: In that example, if I want to retain the `<subelem>`, how would I do that? I can't ignore the nested elements, so I guess using the term text is wrong. I need everything literal in between the main element tags.

Comment: @ConnorTumbleson: Updated to include more examples and a way to capture the 'innerHTML' version.

Comment: I added a little check to make sure it had children, and it worked great. Thanks for your help and dealing with me not able to put code on SO.